# Distortion from output Audio Unit

Tags: core-audio

I am hearing a very loud and harsh distortion sound when I run this simple application.  I am simply instantiating a default output unit and assign a render callback.  And letting the program run in the runloop.  I have detected no errors from Core Audio and everything works as usual except for this distortion.

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


OSStatus render1(void *inRefCon,
                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                 const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                 UInt32 inBusNumber,
                 UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                 AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
   return noErr;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   AudioUnit timerAU;
   UInt32 propsize = 0;       

   AudioComponentDescription outputUnitDesc;
   outputUnitDesc.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
   outputUnitDesc.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
   outputUnitDesc.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
   outputUnitDesc.componentFlags         = 0;
   outputUnitDesc.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

   //Get RemoteIO AU from Audio Unit Component Manager
   AudioComponent outputComp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &outputUnitDesc);

   if (outputComp == NULL) exit (-1);

   CheckError(AudioComponentInstanceNew(outputComp, &timerAU), "comp");       

   //Set up render callback function for the RemoteIO AU.
   AURenderCallbackStruct renderCallbackStruct;
   renderCallbackStruct.inputProc = render1;
   renderCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = nil;//(__bridge void *)(self);

   propsize = sizeof(renderCallbackStruct);

   CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(timerAU,
                                   kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                   kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                   0,
                                   &renderCallbackStruct,
                                   propsize), "set render");

   CheckError(AudioUnitInitialize(timerAU), "init");       

  // tickMethod = completion;

   CheckError(AudioOutputUnitStart(timerAU), "start");

   CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1000, false);

}
```

Comment: Please be so kind to try making your code more readable, by properly formatting it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not seem complete. I don't know about the side effects of silencing the output noise which is probably just undefined behavior. I also don't know what your code would serve for as such. There is an unfinished render callback on the `kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput` which does nothing (it is *not* generating silence!). I know for two ways of silencing it.

In the callback the `ioData` buffers have to be explicitly filled with zeroes, because there's no guarantee they will be initialized empty:

```
Float32 * lBuffer0;
Float32 * lBuffer1;
lBuffer0 = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
lBuffer1 = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;
memset(lBuffer0,  0, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));
memset(lBuffer1,  0, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));
```

Other possibility is to leave the unfinished callback as it is, but declare the `timerAU` to be of `outputUnitDesc.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;`
 instead of
`outputUnitDesc.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;`
and explicity disable I/O before setting the render callback by means of following code:

```
UInt32 lEnableIO = 0;
CheckError(AudioUnitSetProperty(timerAU,
                            kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                            kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                            0,   //output element
                            &lEnableIO,
                            sizeof(lEnableIO)),
"couldn't disable output");
```

I would strongly encourage into studying thoroughly the CoreAudio API and understanding how to set up an audio unit. This is crucial in understanding the matter. I've seen in your code a comment mentioning a `RemoteIO AU`. There is nothing like a `RemoteIO AU` in OSX. In case you're attempting a port from iOS code, please try learning the differences. They are well documented.

Comment: yeah thanks, i realized that the distortion was caused by leftover non-mem-setted memory in my program's heap when i logged out the ioData's buffer's.  i simply for looped through them and zeroed out my float-type samples but i imagine your memset calls are more efficient.  indeed this was a port from iOS and I'm aware that remoteIO is an iOS specific construct and it was only a leftover comment i forgot to delete.  it was interesting that you'd recommend disabling output and that i might try the HAL unit instead of its (presumably "subclassed"?) default output?  of what significance is that?

Comment: fittingly the reason for this distortion comes from my programs intentions as I'm only using this render callback as a source of real-time function invocation at regular intervals and am doing all of my audio-unit sound output on other callbacks or simply sending midi messages to an AUSampler.  hence, the uninitialized noise, presumably being send to the HAL with no `AudioUnitRender()` call which would be there if I used the render callback to actually .. uh .. render anything.   I wonder if there is a better foundation for my "sequencer" built on regular timing than this appropriated callback

Comment: @user5797668, AFAIK, the output in `kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput` is _open_, so you have to programmatically silence the system allocated buffers in order to get silence. In `kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput` you can disable I/O on setup. I dare not call it "subclassing", since CoreAudio API is plain-C. I hope my answer can help.

Comment: sure i meant subclassing in the loose sense that default output builds upon HAL and refines its functionality. CA framework itself uses at least the term objects to describe its functional components.  anyway, i appreciate the help and if you have an idea about my sequencer/timing foundation question please let me know